# Is there a name for the concept of a "co-lower-bound"?

Tags: order-theory

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a poset and  let $Y$ be a subset of $X$. Suppose this collection of objets has the property that for each $x\in X$, there exists a $y\in Y$ such that $x\leq y$. Is there a name for this property?

Here's an example: let $X$ be the collection of open sets of some topological space (with the order being containement: $V\subseteq U$ if and only if $U\leq V$), and let $Y$ be any basis for the topology. Then the property holds.

Another example: let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{N}$. This is the Archimedean property.

Yet another example: let $X$ be the spectrum of some commutative ring with unity (where the ideals are partially ordered by inclusion) and let $Y$ be its maximal spectrum (the collection of maximal ideals).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics)

Comment: I usually encounter this concept when talking about ordinals.

Comment: That was quick! Thank you! I found this concept when I was trying to simplify the computation of a direct limit. If you wish, you can add your comment as an answer so I can resolve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subset $Y$ is called *cofinal* in $X$. See  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics)).